# 3D touch to UITabView

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I am using a `tabViewController` and want to know how I can make a 3D touch action from the home screen bring up a tab. I already have the code but can't seem to get a specific tab to show up; I can only get a window. My AppDelagate.swift is below. Any help?

[image]

```
enum ShortcutIdentifier: String
{
    case First
    case Second

    init?(fullType: String)
    {
        guard let last = fullType.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last else {return nil}
        self.init(rawValue: last)
    }

    var type: String
        {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier! + ".\(self.rawValue)"
    }

}

func handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool
{
    var handled = false

    guard ShortcutIdentifier(fullType: shortcutItem.type) != nil else {return false}
    guard let shortcutType = shortcutItem.type as String? else {return false}

    switch (shortcutType)
    {
    case ShortcutIdentifier.First.type:
        handled = true

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sourcesview") as! UINavigationController
        if let tabBarController = navVC.topViewController as? UITabBarController {
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 4
        }
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        break
    case ShortcutIdentifier.Second.type:
        handled = true

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchview") as! UINavigationController
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        break
    default:
        break
    }


    return handled

}
```

Comment: i would suggest copying and pasting your code rather than uploading a screenshot

Comment: I would suggest pasting only relevant parts of your code. Empty `application:willTerminate:` definitions and such don't make your question clearer.

Comment: Okay. Fixed that too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `selectedTab` property on your `UITabBarController`. I assume that the `UINavigationController` that you load from the nib contains a `UITabBarController` as top view controller, so after loading the navigation controller from the nib you have to access the tab bar controller and set the selected tab property to the desired tab.

```
switch (shortcutType)
    {
    case ShortcutIdentifier.First.type:
        handled = true

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sourcesview") as! UINavigationController
        if let tabBarController = navVC.topViewController as? UITabBarController {
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
        }
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        break
        ...
}
```

Comment: Okay. I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: All of my tabs are just view controllers that are linked to the tab bar controller.

Comment: So just set 'selectedTab' on the tab bar controller to show the tab you want.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question so I can see what you are doing now?

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot from your nib including the document outline (the left row of the IB window)? I cannot see what the problem is without knowing how you built your nib.

Comment: Added the screenshot @joern

Comment: Thanks, but where is your UITabBarController? The thing is you need a reference to your UITabBarController in the `handleShortcutItem` function.